# Is there a way to get Boost Variant's types vector (recursives expanded)

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

Boost Variant class has a member type ***types***. Its a Boost MPL Sequence for types used in template parameters. In the recursive cases such as :

`typename boost::make_recursive_variant<int, std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_>>::type;`

will create a sequence (types member) :

`boost::mpl::l_item<boost::mpl::long_<2>,int,boost::mpl::l_item<boost::mpl::long_<1>,std::vector<boost::variant<boost::detail::variant::recursive_flag<int>,std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_,std::allocator<boost::recursive_variant_> >,boost::detail::variant::void_,boost::detail::variant::void_,...........> >,boost::mpl::l_end> >`

As you can see `std::vector<boost::recursive_variant_,std::allocator<boost::recursive_variant_> >` is not substituted with the original variant type yet.

I found some internal utilities doing this conversion but its undocumented and its hard to follow due macros.

Now I can do it with MPL but it may not match Variant implementation (there are some recursion limits, etc.)

Is there a way to get this type sequences converted with original Variant utilities?

***[Edit]***

My goal is to get :

`boost::mpl::vector<int, std::vector<MyVariantType, std::allocator<MyVariantType>>`

***[Edit]***

This is how I substitute recursively at the moment. My end goal was to write a convenient Boost.Variant wrapper for adding type interfaces (Finished the implementation but not happy for using my own implementation for recursive type substitutions ). (more https://github.com/FictionIO/WrappedVariant )

```
template<typename PlaceholderT, typename WithT>
struct substitute_placeholder
{
    template<typename InputT>
    struct apply
    {
        template<typename T>
        struct substitute
        {
            using type  = T;
        };

        template<template <typename, typename ...> typename T, typename ParamT, typename ... ParamsT>
        struct substitute<T<ParamT, ParamsT...>>
        {
            template<typename ... TypesT>
            struct packed_types{};

            template<typename Type1T, typename Type2T>
            struct pack_types;

            template<typename TypeT, typename ... TypesT>
            struct pack_types<packed_types<TypesT...>, TypeT>
            {
                using type  = packed_types<TypesT..., TypeT>;
            };

            template<typename ... TypesT>
            struct unpack
            {
                using type  = void;
            };

            template<typename ... TypesT>
            struct unpack<packed_types<TypesT...>>
            {
                using type  = T<TypesT...>;
            };

            using originals         = boost::mpl::vector<ParamT, ParamsT...>;
            using func              = typename substitute_placeholder<PlaceholderT, WithT>:: template apply<boost::mpl::_1>;
            using substitutedTypes  = typename boost::mpl::transform<originals, func>::type;
            using packed            = typename boost::mpl::fold<substitutedTypes, packed_types<>, pack_types<boost::mpl::_1, boost::mpl::_2>>::type;
            using type              = typename unpack<packed>::type;
        };

        template<>
        struct substitute<PlaceholderT>
        {
            using type  = WithT;
        };

        using type      = typename substitute<InputT>::type;
    };
};

template<typename ImplT, typename TypesVecT>
struct to_substitude_types_vec
{
    using func      = typename substitute_placeholder<boost::recursive_variant_, ImplT>:: template apply<boost::mpl::_1>;
    using type      = typename boost::mpl::transform<TypesVecT, func>::type;
};

using originalTypes     = typename boost::mpl::copy<VariantT::types, boost::mpl::back_inserter<boost::mpl::vector<>>>::type;
using substitutedTypes  = typename to_substitude_types_vec<VariantT, originalTypes>::type
```